# flexbox example in webkit chrome wanted

Tags: php, html, css

I've been trying to create a layout with a header an footer with content in the middle but when I put lots of content in the page - the content overflows into the footer and the page breaks I've tried using -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap or nowrap and it doesn't work at all if i convert it to a row. So basically I need a page that has a sticky footer that has content body expanded to the footer but if the content is bigger than the page the page shouldn't break. Could someone please make me a page up in the flexbox model the way I explained for chrome much appreciate thanks

here is my code:
CSS:

```
html, body
{
    margin:0px; 
    height:100%; 
    display:-webkit-box; 
    -webkit-box-orient:horizontal; 
    -webkit-flex:1; 
    -webkit-box-flex:1;
}
#wrapper
{
    display:-webkit-box; 
    display:flexbox; 
    -webkit-box-orient:vertical; 
    -webkit-box-flex:1; 
    -webkit-flex-flow:column nowrap; 
    background-color:#f00; 
    height:100% 
}
#body
{
    display:-webkit-box; 
    -webkit-box-orient:vertical; 
    background-color:#ff6a00; 
    flex:1; 
    -webkit-box-flex:1;
}
header
{
    background-color:#4cff00; 
    height:200px
}
footer
{
    background-color:#4cff00; 
    height:200px;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="wrapper">
    <header>Header</header>
    <div id="body">
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
        <p>Body</p>
    </div>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you want

```
html, body
{
    margin:0px; 
    height:100%; 
}
#wrapper
{
    display:-webkit-box; 
    display:flexbox; 
    -webkit-box-orient:vertical; 
    -webkit-box-flex:1; 
    -webkit-flex-flow:column nowrap; 
    background-color:#f00; 
    height:100% ; 

}
#body
{
    display:-webkit-box; 
    -webkit-box-orient:vertical; 
    background-color:#ff6a00; 
    flex:1; 
    -webkit-box-flex:1; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
header
{
    background-color:#4cff00; 
    height:200px
}
footer
{
    background-color:#4cff00; 
    height:200px;
}
```

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/9a95t/)